# How to disable private tenant in OpenSearch dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

**Preface:** I deployed the OpenSearch using Amazon OpenSearch Service.
I faced the issue of auto-redirecting from Global to Private tenant in OpenSearch Dashboards after some time (up to 10 minutes).
I saw in other answers (they were related to Kibana and ElasticSearch) how to proceed to directories with a configuration file (opensearch.yml, opensearch-dashboards.yml), but how to do it with OpenSearch on AWS? Can I connect via CLI to cluster directly, go through files, and create/edit a config file or maybe API which will update my config?

Comment: check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/set-advanced-settings-with-the-amazon-opensearch-service-dashboards-api/

Comment: @Riz thanks, I already checked this some time ago... it's about timezone settings, but what about updating tenant settings (disabling private tenant it's my case). Where can I check API or answer how to disable private tenant via API or config file I guess?

Comment: @Riz OpenSearch docs says: "To use the PUT and PATCH methods for the configuration APIs, add the following line to opensearch.yml:"
How I can directly get access to the opensearch.yml file? How I can connect to my cluster on AWS and go through files?

Comment: You cannot access the yml file. Maybe you need to open a support ticket if you can.

Comment: @Riz so, I don't have the possibility to change the tenant settings (or even the rest of the settings) directly via configuration file?

Comment: You have only api available to make changes in aws managed opensearch. You can't connect to the cluster in anyway. So no, you won't be able to access the config file.